# libarchive is broken for RAR on Linux - any similar C library alternatives?

Tags: linux, library, c, file-compression, rar

I'm using [libarchive](https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive) to read and scan through a generic set of archives (mostly *7z*, *RAR* and *zip*).
The library interface is quite simple and although supports only linear archive processing, doesn't have a clear interface to distinguish between *files* and *directories*, it kinda works for my needs.

Unfortunately I've discovered that *RAR* archives are poorly supported (there is a defect since [2015](https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive/issues/373) which hasn't been tackled yet) and I was wondering if there's any other C (or C++) similar library to be able to open generic packages and extract files (not interested in writing compressed data).

What are alternatives to such library (if at all) which would be exposing a C (or C++) interface and easily available on Linux (Ubuntu preferably)?